# How can I know when an icon is clicked using tinymce editor?

Tags: tinymce

How can I know when an icon is clicked using tinymce editor? Actually I am trying to solve the issue of multiple windows opening when we click multiple times to the `jbimage` plugin icon.
I want to make sure that when there is already an uploaded image window then the second popup should not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will have to adjust the plugin code and decide this case using a variable you set to true when the popup opens and reset it when the popup is being closed.